# New York Tourism logo

Tags: designers

How the designers responsible for the NewYork Tourism logo and how they came up with an ideas? Which the logos represent to each place?

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, can you [edit] to explain better what you want to know? Check [ask] if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

[Milton Glaser](https://www.miltonglaser.com/) designed the ["I Love New York"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Love_New_York) logo, circa 1976, for the New York Tourism Board. Realize that "I Love New York" is the state song as well.

> ... in the back of a taxi and was drawn with red crayon on scrap paper.

As for how he "came up with the idea" -- I'm afraid you'd have to ask him. But there are numerous articles about it if you search the internet.

I do not understand your second sentence/question regarding "each place". That may be because not everyone lives in or near New York.

Comment: Better hurry up on asking, you may not have much time left - Milton turned 90 this year!